# Python - Looping columns to replace integer value with categorical value based on dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that shows the categorical to numeric conversion. Then I have a data frame that shows the numeric value in the column.

```
dict0={'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}

Column1         Column2            Column3
1               127                3
```

I want to change the numeric value output back to categorical only where that value occurs. So using the example above, my output would look like:

```
Column1         Column2            Column3
one             127                three
```

1 and 3 then where in the dictionary and where changed back to 'one' and 'three'

Comment: What should happen if you have ```{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':3}```?

Comment: That isn't a valid dictionary, are you looking for the string representation of a number or showing the *keys* rather than the values? What have you tried?

Comment: can you show the code that changes in the first part?

Comment: I'm looking to convert the numeric value back to the string in my output dataframe where the numeric value is in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You need to flip the values in `dict0` for this to work.

```py
nums = {
    'one': 1, 
    'two': 2, 
    'three': 3, 
    'four': 4
}

nums_flipped = {
    v: k
    for k, v in nums.items()
}
# nums_flipped = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'}
```

Once you have this, you need to replace the `FeatureValue_x` by `nums_flipped[FeatureValue_x]` if the FeatureValue_x is a number.

For example:

```py
feature_values = [1, 2, 'some string', 3]

output = [
    nums_flipped.get(feature_value, feature_value)
    for feature_value in feature_values
]
# output = ['one', 'two', 'some string', 'three']
```

Based on how your data is stored, write some similar code to solve your problem.

Comment: The first part to get the key makes sense. However, where I'm stuck is looping through multiple columns to find where the key matches column value and replacing with string

Comment: Please show how the values in the column are stored. @dcrowley01

Comment: The columns are in a dataframe, df. So I have the key value pairs in the dictionary and df.Column1, df.Column2, and df.Column3 in df.

Comment: Loop over it and create a new dataframe, maybe? @dcrowley01

Answer (score 0):

do you mean revert/invert?

```
dikt = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
inverted = {value: key for key, value in zip(dikt.keys(), dikt.values())}
inverted
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Comment: `dikt.items()` does the job.